# Accessing ViewBag.Something using JS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In the MVC project I have an assignment:

```
ViewBag.SomeOne = "one";
ViewBag.SomeTwo = "two";
```

On the page, I'm displaying the first directly:

```
<div id="one">@ViewBag.SomeOne</div>
```

The other, isn't displayed at first. I've been instructed to create a jQuery expression that combines the two and creates a DIV element with them in it upon a click on the visible one. So I went:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#one").click(function () {
      var toghether = "";
      $("#both").append(together);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Now, the problem is that I can't find a nice way to access the value of *ViewBag.One* and can't find **any** way to access the value of *ViewBag.Two*.

I went cheating like this:

```
$("#one").text();
```

How can I make it better? And how can I access the other?

Answer (score 2):

you can access `ViewBag` value from javascript :

```
var toghether = '@(ViewBag.SomeOne)' + ' @(ViewBag.SomeTwo)';
```

for example :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ViewBag.SomeOne = "one";
  ViewBag.SomeTwo = "two";
}
```

in `View` :

```
@section JavaScript{
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#one").click(function () {
          var toghether = '@(ViewBag.SomeOne)' + ' @(ViewBag.SomeTwo)';
          $("#both").append(together);
        }
      }
  </script>
}
```

Comment: Oh, this was nice. I always put in the *script* tag outside *section*. Didn't think of **this**.

Comment: it's because I defined section in my `_Layout` page, you can put your code outside of section.